# Python lxml html.fromstring не работает

Tags: html, python, lxml

Парсю эту html страницу:
http://cogcc.state.co.us/COGIS/DrillingPermitsList.cfm
Сначала скачиваю с помощью requests

```
    import requests
from xmlWorker import HtmlParser

url = "http://cogcc.state.co.us/COGIS/DrillingPermitsList.cfm"
postDataForPending = {"listtype":"Pending",
            "country": "All",
            "B1": "Go!"}
postDataForApproved = {"listtype":"Approved",
            "country": "All",
            "B1": "Go!"}
response = requests.post(url, data = postDataForPending)
htmlText = response.text
print(htmlText)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    htmlParser = HtmlParser(htmlText)
    print(htmlParser.get_received())
```

А потом парсю это дело lxml

```
class HtmlParser:
    xpathRoot = '/tr[position()>1 and position()<{0}+2]/'
    xpathToReceivedfirst = xpathRoot + 'td[1]/font/text()'

    def __init__(self, htmlText):
        logf = open("download.log", "w")
        try:
            self.document = lxmlHtmlParser.fromstring(htmlText)
        except Exception as e:  # most generic exception you can catch
            logf.write(str(e))
        finally:
                # optional clean up code
            pass

    def get_received(self):
        xp = self.xpathToReceivedfirst.format(maxRecordsToParse)
        receivedElements = self.document.xpath(xp)
        return receivedElements
```

Никаких ошибок не выводится. Проблема в том, что при дебаге все аттрибуты self.document или не заданы, или равны, скажем '\n', соответственно все xpath-ы возвращают пустые листы.
При том BeautifulSoup парсит элементы нормально.
Html файл вроде валидный. В чем проблема таки совсем не понимаю

**UPDATED**

Я пропарсил одну таблицу bs-опом, удалил все переводы кареток, пробелы между тэгами. Всё равно ничего не работает, браузер нормально определяет и рендерит эту таблицу, сохраненную в файл

Comment: С меня конечно плохой питонист (и код представлен частично), но что это lxmlHtmlParser и почему один слеш в начале xpathRoot

Comment: lxmlHtmlParser  - алиас для lxml.html
я протестил мой xpath на одном стороннем сервисе, всё работало как я и ожидал

Comment: Создайте минимальный пример ввода, который покажет проблему (например, выбросите половину html, посмотрите что проблема осталась, выбросите половину от остатка пока не сможете выбросить больше ничего. Приведите ожидаемый вывод (что beautifulsoup выводит, и что вместо этого с lxml получается. [mcve]